# StreamXmlRecordReader not working properly in hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop-streaming

Using hadoop I tried to split following xml in separate nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pages>
    <page>
            <title>Sourav</title>
    </page>
    <page>
            <title>Gaurav</title>
    </page>
    <page>
            <title>sachin</title>
    </page>
    <page>
            <title>Rahul</title>
    </page>
</pages>
```

like

```
<page>
        <title>abc</title>   
</page>
```

I ran it by following command

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1.jar -inputreader "StreamXmlRecordReader,begin=<page>,end=</page>" -input /usr/root/xml  -output /usr/root/xmloutput
```

but instead of four single nodes I got following output

```
<page>
    <title>Sourav</title>
</page> 
<page>
    <title>Gaurav</title>
</page> 
<page>
    <title>sachin</title>
</page> 
<page>
    <title>Rahul</title>
</page>
```

and

```
<page>
    <title>sachin</title>
</page> 
<page>
    <title>Rahul</title>
</page>
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Any insight on what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not doing anything wrong.

This is an irritating bug in Hadoop Streaming.

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-577
```

It is a known bug in 0.20, but they say it is fixed in 0.22.  I don't know about that, but unfortunately it is broken again in 1.0.4.

In the meantime, you can preprocess your xml to something nicer for streaming.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've wasted a couple of hours on wondering why my Mapper takes so long to execute relatively simple piece of code.

In CDH4, there are two versions: 0.20 (the old API), and the 2.0.0 (the new API). The new version does not include StreamXMLRecordReader. Do you know any better way to use that?

Comment: No, sorry. I preprocess my XML outside of hadoop and convert the XML to CSV.  This might not be helpful to your situation, but if you have the resources, it might be an option.  Another option is to grab the source code of hadoop and implement StreamXmlRecordReader on your own, with the apparent bug fix that went in to 0.22.